# IE wont dynamically disable/enable textbox using jquery while other would

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I need to disable or enable a textbox based on the selected value in a dropdown. This is the code i am using.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

if ($('#fragmentation').val() == 'NONE') { // if fragmentation is none
    alert("inside document ready");
    $('#fragmentSize').attr('disabled','disabled');
}

$('#fragmentation').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != 'NONE') {
        $('#fragmentSize').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#fragmentSize').val('');
        $('#fragmentSize').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

The code works perfectly fine in all browsers except IE. **I wish to make it work for IE8 and higher** but for now even IE9 wont run it. The alert box i put there is showing up hence the code is reaching there in IE and there is no error in console or anything else.

I even tried using these:

```
$('#fragmentSize').prop('disabled','disabled');
$('#fragmentSize').prop('disabled',false);
$('#fragmentSize').prop('disabled','false');
$('#fragmentSize').attr('disabled',false);
$('#fragmentSize').attr('disabled','false');
```

All of these work in other browsers but IE just wont budge.

EDIT: 
I don't know if it was plain ignorance from my side or a horrible way to render a disabled field. The ultimate verdict is that it was running perfectly fine, only **i didn't realized that a disabled field in IE looks just like a normal field.** I was so used to looking at the disabled fields in firefox and chrome that i couldn't identify it in IE. Anyways, there was no problem at all, so i don't know if i should keep the question or delete it. Sorry for wasting your time guys.

Comment: can you please share the fiddle?

Comment: Which part doesn't work? The initial disable, or the one in the change event?

Comment: This code is working fine on my computer. For IE8 also. I am using jQuery v1.8.2

Comment: Any disable wont work. Neither is it disabled upon page load nor anything happens on change.

Answer (score 0):

Following code is working:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    if ($('#fragmentation').val() == 'NONE') { // if fragmentation is none
        alert("inside document ready");
        $('#fragmentSize').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }

    $('#fragmentation').change(function() {    
        if ($(this).val() != 'NONE') {
            console.log('NOT NONE');
            $('#fragmentSize').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            console.log(' NONE');
            $('#fragmentSize').val('');
            $('#fragmentSize').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
    });
</script>
```

```
<select id="fragmentation">
<option value="NONE">1</option>
<option value="NONE">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="fragmentSize" value="HELLO">
</body>
```

Is there any difference between in code?
Can you post HTML code also?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble mate. Please check the edit i just made.